# Android application on Google Play - incompatible with all devices

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt

I trying to find the answer for 2 days on StackOverflow and other services without any luck.
I have published an app to Google Play. It's there but it's incompatible with most of the devices.
I ran tests on Nexus 7 both using Eclipse and TestFlight to install it and there was no problem. So I'm almost sure it is related to the AndroidManifest.

Here is aapt dump badging result:

```
Application.apk

package: name='com.test.application' 

versionCode='1' 

versionName='1.0'

sdkVersion:'11'

targetSdkVersion:'19'

uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'

uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'

uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'

application-label:'Application'

application-label-da:'Application'

application-label-el:'Application'

application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'

application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png'

application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png'

application-icon-480:'res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png'

application: label='Application' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'

application-debuggable

launchable-activity: name='com.test.application.activity.Launcher'  

label='Application' icon=''

uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'

uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested 

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'

uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'

uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch screen 

unless explicitly made optional'

uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.landscape'

uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.screen.landscape','one or more activities have 
specified a landscape orientation'

main

other-activities

supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'

supports-any-density: 'true'

locales: '--_--' 'da' 'el'

densities: '160' '240' '320' '480'
```

and here is Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.application"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:name=".ApplicationApplication">
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.application.activity.Launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.application.activity.SomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|locale">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.application.activity.AnotherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|locale">
         </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The signed apk was built using Android Studio.
What seems suspicious is this "application-debuggable".
Do You guys have any clue why on Earth it is incompatible with, let's say Nexus 7?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio try to add `debuggable false` in your build.gradle file under release buildType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after all it turns out that there was no problem at all.
Guy responsible for publication process set country restrictions.
That's why app was not compatible with all devices in specific country.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it saying, app is not compatible.

It is showing error on device not only because minSDKversion but also google play concern about your given permission on the manifest file as well.

Like if you entered something like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Your tab will not support it.

So instead of using `uses-permission` use  `<uses-feature>`. And in java file check for it that your needed hardware is available or not.

For `<uses-feature>` see the below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference

**In case If you use this you have to update your manifest like this:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false"/>
```

You have to put `<uses-permission>` along with its required `<uses-feature>`.

**And a small tips if it will help you:**

- You have to keep in mind about `android:minSdkVersion` as well to make it compatible
  with lower version device. As you have to set it like: `android:minSdkVersion="11"`.

Comment: Ok, but as You can see in this specific manifest there is nothing that could influence tablet incompatilibity. Have You checked attached manifest and aapt dump badging result?

Comment: you have given permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET. You have to give the feature of this as well like my final example. @narath

Comment: Ok, but I'm still not convinced it will change a thing. Because in many apps there are  only permissions not uses-features and there is no problem.

Comment: But this is the only issue for which app is not showing in some other device like tab(I am saying it from my personal experience).

Answer (score 0):

In manifest set  `android:minSdkVersion="11"`  - this means that all the devices below Android 3.0 - will not support. Or misrepresented that the problem with the above version 3.0 devices still hit in the list is not supported?

Comment: There was problem with all devices even with Android 4.X